# Update CMake on a Microsoft-hosted agent in Azure DevOps

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, azure-devops

I'm currently setting up different agents for our CI-pipeline. I'm using a Microsoft-hosted Ubuntu 18.04 agent that comes with CMake 3.12.4.
However, our projects requires CMake 3.14.5. Normally I would try to update CMake but the standard repository does not provide the version needed.
I tried to update cmake by using the Kitware APT Repository but `cmake --version` still outputs 3.12.4.
I was expecting the update to override the cmake command but it still refers to the old version.

I also tried to remove the old cmake version before but I got a message that cmake could not be found.

What I did now to make everything work is to download the required version from `https://cmake.org` via shell and install it using make.
This works and also allows me to later use `- task: CMake@1` with the correct, newly installed version.

I was wondering if there is another way to update CMake to a specific version, since downloading and installing CMake takes nearly 10 minutes.

**EDIT:**

Microsoft-hosted Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS now come with CMake version 3.16.2

Comment: @squareskittles: What topics can I ask about here? ... [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ...

Comment: @Pedro Although the OP may find help on those other sites, I agree with your point. I"ll retract the vote!

Comment: I was searching for similar questions and most questions that I found related to azure-devops were posted on stackoverflow.
Also, I would say that the most important aspect of the question is about azure-devops and not about "how to install cmake".

Comment: @amka Not get your response for several days. If merlin's answer is helpful to you ,you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you indeed want to install `CMake 3.14.5`and use it in next tasks with our Hosted Ubuntu agent, you must `remove` them firstly and then `re-install` the corresponding version. Because different with some modules or packages, `cmake` is a tool that you must install it into system. In another word, just download the package could not actually override the default version `3.12.4`.

So, you must use such similar script to achieve version upgrade:

```
echo Write your commands here
sudo apt remove cmake
wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.14/cmake-3.14.5.tar.gz
tar xf cmake-3.14.5.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.14.5
./configure
sudo make install
cmake --version
```

The above steps/logic is not complex, just remove `cmake` from agent, download package(`tar.gz`) from official `cmake`, then extract and install it into Hosted agent.

**BUT**, same with install the the `cmake` into local Linux system, the last step **`install`** will take a bit more time, which means it would lead your builds take nearly 15 minute to finish the install into Hosted linux agent job.

[image]

---

Anyway, very appreciate your love to our hosted agent and now I need do something to not disappoint this favorite.

I made a commit and raise the pull request into our repos: [Update cmake.sh to 3.15 stable](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/pull/1424). This **PR** would be merged and the required `cmake` version will be available once our PM reviewed it. I'm very sure next week, the satisfied hosted Ubuntu agent would be available for you, and you will not need addition scripts and take **15** minutes to upgrade the **cmake** version any more.

Comment: As I wrote, I already accomplished to download and install cmake using a shell script. Note that I did not need to remove the current cmake version.
However, I was thinking of a more intuitive way: e.g. adding the kitware repository and apt update / install using their provided latest cmake version.

I'm looking forward to the PR and will try out the new Ubuntu agent.

If everything works fine, I will mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @amka I know, remove or not does not has any affect on the time. I think you have known from the log that the step which is taking the most time is **install** the new version cmake into agent.  This cannot be avoid because like you install tool into your local system, most of time is used to install the tool into system. I don’t think this will be different in VSTS. So I raise a commit to let you avoid this time waste. Hope my PM can back soon then he can approve this PR.

Comment: @amka, sorry for delay because our team is working on migrating the image repos in github. Has been migrate the new pr in our new image repos: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/pull/141. Please track this.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you run a pipeline with Microsoft-hosted agents, you get a fresh virtual machine. The virtual machine is discarded after one use. So it is a hassle to update CMake every time.

You can deploy a self-hosted agent and then enable CMake for your self-hosted agent. Self-hosted agents give you more control to install dependent software needed for your builds and deployments. Also, machine-level caches and configuration persist from run to run, which can boost speed.

Here are the steps about enabling CMake for self-hosted agent:

1.[Deploy an agent.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install)

2.[Install CMake](https://cmake.org/install/) and make sure to add it to the path of the user that the agent is running as on your agent machine.

3.In your web browser, navigate to Agent pools: Choose Azure DevOps -> Organization settings -> Choose **Agent pools**.

4.Navigate to the capabilities tab: 
From the **Agent pools** tab -> select the desired agent pool -> Select **Agents** and choose the desired agent -> Choose the **Capabilities** tab

5.Click **Add capability** and set the fields to `cmake` and `yes`.

6.Click Save changes.

For details,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/cmake?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-enable-cmake-for-my-on-premises-agent).

Comment: I don't want to use self-hosted agents. I know how to setup an agent on my own and that I am able to configure this agent myself.
I'm especially interested in the Microsoft-hosted agents as this does not require me to provide hardware myself.
Everything works fine with Windows and macOS as both agents provide the correct CMake-Version. I wouldn't want to miss this just because of Ubuntu not providing the required CMake-Version.